# MVC3 is it possible to serve a view section from a controller action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes

Suppose I have `index.cshtml`

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
@model SomeModel

@section JS{     
    content1
    content2
    content3
}

<div> View Content </div>
```

Is there any way I could have a controller action that would serve ONLY the section JS for a request for `index.js`?

Such that navigating to `http://somesite/index.js` would return

```
    content1
    content2
    content3
```

**Edit:** Some further thoughts on this. My goal would be along the lines say creating a layout page that requires a JS section programmatically, and then composing the View to that layout page and then returning the results of this.

Psuedo code example:

```
var layout = new LayoutPage();
layout.DefineSection("JS", required: true);
layout.Compose(View("index"))
return layout;
```

I'm not set on achieving that with what I described but I feel that might offer some more insight on what I'd like to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this (but you'd have to write your own controller action to do it properly)

#### Index.cshml

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.TestModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
<p>
    To learn more about ASP.NET MVC visit <a href="http://asp.net/mvc" title="ASP.NET MVC Website">http://asp.net/mvc</a>.
</p>

@section JS {
    blahblahblah
}
```

#### JSLayout:

```
@RenderSection("JS")
```

#### Your controller Action

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    return View("Index", "_JSLayout", yourModel);
}
```

This will output only the `JS` section. If you want to do it programatically then it will take a bit.

Comment: +1 this type of information is exactly what I was looking for. Stretching these universally just comes to having the right base controller class and/or right FilterAttributes

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do it would be to make the content of that section into a partial view, and return the partial view from the controller action.

Comment: Not really what I'm looking for, I'm thinking more along the lines of dynamically create a layout a page that defines that requires the JS section and then composing the layout with the view page and then returning that. I guess this is worth adding to the question.